# Bывести на экран текст в зависимости от страницы

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть предложение в React JS которая должна, в зависимости от страницы на которую находится пользователь показать иной или другой текст который находится в этом массиве:

```js
const urls = [{
    route: "/home",
    title: "home"
}, {
    route: "/info",
    title: "info"
    sub: [
        {
            route: "/about",
            title: "about"
        }
    ]

}
];
```

для примера, если пользователь находится на странице `Home`на экран должно выводиться `home`, a если пользователь находится на странице `about`, на экран должно выводиться `info / about`, и так далее.
для получения некоторых данных Я знаю что можно использовать `withRouter()`. 
Как вывести текст?

Comment: Этот массив в компонент передается или как всё происходит? Какой вообще смысл в этом массиве?

Comment: @ hu-fo-of-ex, этот массив обозначает все пути которые передаются в руторе

Comment: Руторе? 8 символов

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex,  Что ты имеешь в виду?

Comment: Я не могу понять, если я нахожусь, например, на странице `about`, мне нужно пробежать по этому массиву сравнить пути и если они совпадают вывести `title` ? Это какие-то абсолютно лишние и странные телодвижения.

Comment: Или на основе этого массива создаются роуты? Если да, то покажи как ты это делаешь.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, к примеру я нахожусь на странице about ( url =  www.site.com/info/about ),  мне нужно пробежать по этому массиву сравнить пути и если они совпадают вывести `title`, то есть текст будет `info / about`. как это сделать?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-https-v9tzp Надеюсь разберешься... Не разберешься, спрашивай, но я отвечу уже только завтра.